# Ethernet not working on Ubuntu 16.04 Dell Vostro

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ethernet, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 3446, dual-booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. The ethernet works on Windows but not on Ubuntu and I am also unable to find ethernet drivers for Ubuntu on the official Dell website. It was working previously but recently I had to format and reinstall Windows and Ubuntu.

The output for ifconfig -a is as follows:-

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:8552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1417162 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1417162 (1.4 MB)

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:bb:58:51:21:ec  
      inet addr:10.2.6.175  Bcast:10.2.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3a25:6cd2:f287:2867/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:152285 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:46852 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:68149773 (68.1 MB)  TX bytes:6974198 (6.9 MB)
```

Other outputs are as follows:-

```
saptarsi@saptarsi-Vostro-3446:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)


saptarsi@saptarsi-Vostro-3446:~$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
No data available

saptarsi@saptarsi-Vostro-3446:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: 4c:bb:58:51:21:ec
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.13.0-36-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.2.6.175 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f7800fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff


saptarsi@saptarsi-Vostro-3446:~$ echo -e "blacklist b43\nblacklist ssb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist b43
blacklist ssb

saptarsi@saptarsi-Vostro-3446:~$ sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r816
[21476.866351] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[21476.866367] r8169 0000:07:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[21476.879738] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffa9004066d000, 74:e6:e2:2e:d6:02, XID 0c000800 IRQ 47
[21476.879742] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]

saptarsi@saptarsi-Vostro-3446:~$ grep r8169 /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist r8169
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# map the specific PCI IDs instead of blacklisting the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# to blacklist the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:#blacklist r8169
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r816` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: So now there is a driver and an interface, eth0. Can you click the Network Manager icon and connect? We will need to go on to find and correct why the driver doesn't load automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is working now. But I am required to do modprobe every time I restart.  How do I make this change permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ethernet doesn't start because the driver didn't load automatically as expected. First, let's see if we determine why. Is it blacklisted? Check from the terminal:

```
grep r8169 /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

If you find a result, post it and I'll edit this answer to suggest a correction.

We can get the driver to load automatically with:

```
sudo -i
echo r8169 >> /etc/modules
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: I did blacklist it since it wasn't working in the first place and to prevent r8169 from loading and instead load r8168. But the latter didn't load at all it seems.